# How to fix a screen orientation permanently in flutter?

Tags: flutter, screen, orientation, landscape, portrait

Suppose my application has two screens (screen A and B). My app starts from screen A in which I have set device orientation to portrait up. Such as-

```
Future<void> main() async {
setUpLocator();
// debugPaintSizeEnabled=true;
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
MobileAds.instance.initialize();
await Firebase.initializeApp();

runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeNotifier>(
create: (_) => ThemeNotifier(),
child: MyApp(),
));
}
```

Normally it works fine and does not rotate the screen but the problem is in screen B where I have used a youtube player plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter). When I turn on full screen mode of youtube player it rotates the screen which is not a problem but if I return to screen A from B while in full screen mode(youtube player) then screen A also appears in landscape mode. But I don't want screen A in landscape mode at all. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can also set for particular screen in `init` like below and also make sure it is called,

```
@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
  ]);
}
```

Comment: if you are using for particular screen then it is fine because you don't need to access it outside of your screen.